# winston log level/ hide log levels

Tags: node.js, winston

As far as I understood has Winston a hierarchy in its logging levels. You can set the level with `winston.level = 'error'` and all levels below should not be shown. Unfortunately I still get the logs of info and debug shown in my console.

**Question 1):**

How to really set winston to show me only the log level

**Question 2)**

Why is Debug anyways shown in the console, I configured it to show up in a log file (what it additionally does)

```
winston = require('winston')
winston.emitErrs = true
logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      level: 'info'
      filename: 'logs/log.log'
      handleExceptions: true
      json: true
      maxsize: 5242880 #5MB
      maxFiles: 5
      colorize: false
      timestamp: true
    }),
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level: 'debug'
      handleExceptions: true
      json: false
      colorize: true
    })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
})
winston.level = 'error'

module.exports = logger
module.exports.stream = {
  write: (message, encoding) ->
    logger.info(message)
}
```

The code is basically from this tut:
http://tostring.it/2014/06/23/advanced-logging-with-nodejs/

Answer (score 3):

Now I got the concept. It logs everything up to the log level in the defined transport. So I guess it is not possible to stream debug just to console and info to the log without manipulating the order.

This does not log debug in the console:

```
new winston.transports.Console({
  level: 'info'
  handleExceptions: true
  json: false
  colorize: true
})
```

My first assumption was that I can specify a transport for each log level and then decide how much logging I want to have with:
`winston.setLevels(winston.config.syslog.levels)`

e.g. 
error to mongoDb
info to log.log file
debug to console